# How to attach a file to an existing pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, latex, pypdf

I have a pdf created with latex and I have to attach a file to this pdf.

I´ve tried this code but the output is a pdf blanked but indeed the file was attached. I have also tried to merge the output file and the original file but the output detaches the file.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
from PyPDF2 import dfFileReader,PdfFilewriter

output = pdf2.PdfFileWriter()

with open ("test.pdf", "rb") as f:
    input_pdf = pdf2.PdfFileReader(f)
    output.appendPagesFromReader(input_pdf)

with open("test.xml", "rb") as xmlFile:
    output.addAttachment("test.xml", xmlFile.read())

with open ("test2.pdf", "ab") as f:
    output.write(f)
```

Solution (partial):

I wrote this in the latex file that generates the pdf, and the file was embedded/attached to the pdf. But I couldn´t find the way to do it in python.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{embedfile}
\begin{document}
\embedfile{test-ansi.tex}
 text \end{document}
```

Comment: You can directly attach files when you create your pdf https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2

Comment: thx, I ended using embeded. But you give the lead to solve it.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\begin{document}
\embedfile{test-ansi.tex} text
\end{document}

Comment: Can you summarise your solution in a quick answer? This will make it easier for future users with the same problem to find it